# www.wixsite.com is pointing to localhost

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

This is strange but when I am typing [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com) in my browser it is pointing to localhost.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I have Apache2 installed and running. It is happening only when I connect my laptop to my D-Link wifi router (DWR-921 HW:C3 FW:3.1.6)

> ping [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com)
>
> PING [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com) (127.0.0.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.39): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
>
> 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.39): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms

and

> tracepath [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com)
>
> 1:  localhost                                             0.144ms
> reached
>
> Resume: pmtu 65535 hops 1 back 1

when I check my apache2 status it says

> apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
> domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally
> to suppress this message

For 127.0.1.1, 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.39 I am getting Apache2 Default Page "It works!"

I am totally confused and donno why [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com) is showing localhost. I can't get preview of my wix page located at http://heartforjapan.wixsite.com/online it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Did you use a online tool to create your own website?

Comment: “It is happening only when I connect my laptop to my D-Link wifi router” ⇠ then it is something that you configured in your router, not the notebook 

Comment: How do I check whether all those 3 IPs 127.0.1.1, 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.39 are been served from my laptop or from internet? Do you think there is a loop in route?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have an alias in your /etc/hosts

Try this:

> cat /etc/hosts

If there is a line entry like

127.0.0.39   [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com)

then

> ```
> sudo vi /etc/hosts
> ```

( or any other editor of your choice in the place of vi )

and remove that line.

Good luck :)

Comment: I have checked cat /etc/hosts and it has only two entries, (1) 127.0.0.1 localhost and (2) 127.0.1.1 "my laptop ID"

Comment: Then it's something emanating from your router's setup. Try opening it's setup page and locating redirection/mapping/virtual ips etc. It's not an Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out on the other day but forgot to post the reason here. I am writing this because someone may encounter same issue and look for solution, and this might help them.

Actually [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com) was blocked for some reason in the network of my ISP at home. Therefore, when I tried to access it at home it routed the URL to my local server in laptop, i.e. localhost

To prevent that I changed my localhost port to 8080. After that when I visit [www.wixsite.com](http://www.wixsite.com), the browser shows DNS error which means the URL is blocked in my ISP.

I hope this will solve confusions of many others like me.